# Filezilla client cannot retrieve the list files from the server

Tags: networking, ftp, webserver

I have setup a filezilla server and I can manage to access it locally with the filezilla client. When I am trying to access it from different PC  I got the following error:

> Status: Connecting to IP:Port...
>
> Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
>
> Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
>
> Status: Connected
>
> Status: Retrieving directory listing...
>
> Command: PWD
>
> Response: 257 "/" is current directory.
>
> Command: TYPE I
>
> Response: 200 Type set to I
>
> Command: PASV
>
> Command: MLSD
>
> Response: 425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
>
> Error: Failed to retrieve directory listing

Any idea what I am doing wrong in server setup?

EDIT: WHat I try was to follow [that instructions](http://www.howtogeek.com/140352/how-to-host-an-ftp-server-on-windows-with-filezilla/). THe whole log file:

```
Status: Connecting to 195.251.117.149:53035...
Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
Status: Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS.
Status: Connected
Status: Retrieving directory listing...
Command:    PWD
Response:   257 "/" is current directory.
Command:    TYPE I
Response:   200 Type set to I
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (195,251,117,149,211,92)
Command:    MLSD
Response:   425 Can't open data connection for transfer of "/"
Error:  Failed to retrieve directory listing
```

I tried to downgrade filezilla client from 3.14 to 3.8 however I received the same error as well as when I tried to turn off firewall from server PC.

Comment: Is your question about the Insecure message, or the fact that you can't list the files? Because they are two different things. Are you also using the FileZilla client on the "different PC"?  Is the "different PC" in the same LAN as the server? What adjustments did you make (if any) to the firewall on the FTP server machine?

Comment: Is this a log file from FileZilla FTP client? You must be using some ancient version. The FileZilla uses `EPSV` instead of `PASV` for ages.

Comment: Anyway, show us a corresponding log file from the server.

Comment: Also I'm missing a response to the `PASV` command. It's rather strange. Did you redact the log? I guess so. Can you show us a complete log instead?

Comment: Though I'd guess this is a common firewall/NAT issue.

Comment: My basic question is why I cannot list the files. I thought that the issue was on that error. I am using FileZilla client in the other pc. The other pc is in the same LAN. I add exception on the port I have create (in the server's pc).

Comment: @Martin I used the last version of FileZilla client.

Comment: I tried both in the same and different LAN I got the same message with the last update of the client.

Comment: So at least show us the complete log file.

Comment: @JoseRamon Did you setup this webserver by yourself ? I think you have misconfigured **chroot** or it is being blocked by **selinux**

Comment: Yes I followed the provided link.

Answer (score 2):

That is not an error, it's a notification. You have chosen to use FTP over port 21, which is not encrypted and thus someone listening on the network can try to catch your login and see what you download. In a local network this all might make no difference if you trust the computers connected.

If that is not good enough, you can use SFTP or FTP over TLS, or SSH, which are all encrypted. If you want to use those, open the proper ports on the server, configure Filezilla to use the proper service and port, and disable FTP. Then connect to the server with a client that supports such connections. The Filezilla client is of course a good choice to use at the other computer.

---

**Update**

The security message is like "you're using the dirt road - the highway is safer to drive". It has nothing to do with listing the files. You probably set the wrong folder in the server settings.

See [**How to Host an FTP Server on Windows with FileZilla**](http://www.howtogeek.com/140352/how-to-host-an-ftp-server-on-windows-with-filezilla/).

You need to set the folder, create a user, link both and set the rights for that user (uploading, downloading, deleting).

Comment: However I am not able to access the directory and to see the files inside from other PC.

Comment: @JoseRamon - Verify if the server is configured to only accept secure FTP connections or not.

Comment: @JoseRamon If your question is about "Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS", then this answer is (mostly) correct -- except it's the client issuing the Status messages shown, not the server.

Comment: My basic question is why I cant access to the list of folders from the client.

Comment: @JoseRamon If that's your question, you should put that in your question title, instead of the *"Insecure server, it does not support FTP over TLS"*.

Comment: You need to create a user, set the folder and proper rights for the user to that folder. See my updated answer.

Comment: @SPRBRN this was the link I already followed. I manage to open the listing folder locally but when I tried to open from other PC I got the mentioned issues.

Comment: I have already made that setup. Is there any option for blocking external ip?

Comment: You use FTP, that's port 21 normally. The firewall on the server has to allow traffic on that port. If this is not a production server, you can test this easily by stopping the firewall entirely. If it works after the firewall has stopped, you know the cause. Then start it again, because that's what you want. Then open port 21 (for FTP) and try again. If you use something else, the port number may be different.

Comment: I have change the 21 port from the settings as suggested in the mentioned post. I have add a exception in the firewall for that port.

Comment: I tried to turn off the firewall from server PC. I tried again to connect to server however I received the same message.